# Error while running Scala code - Databricks 7.3LTS and above

Tags: scala, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks

I am running databricks 7.3LTS and having errors while trying to use scala bulk copy.
The error is:
object sqldb is not a member of package com.microsoft.
I have installed correct sqlconnector drivers but not sure how to fix this error.
The installed drivers are:

```
com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.1.0.
```

also i have installed the JAR dependencies as below:

```
spark_mssql_connector_2_12_1_1_0.jar
```

i couldnt find any scala code example for the above configurations on the internet.
my scala code sample is as below:

```
%scala
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
```

as soon as i run this command i get the error

```
Object sqldb is not a member of package com.microsoft.azure
```

any help please

Comment: please write what you want to achieve, not what doesn't work... Also, add a bigger piece of code

Comment: Simply my scala bulcopy code to SQLMI is not working on Databricks Rutnime 7.3 and above. it is working fine on runtime 5.5LTs.

Answer (score 0):

In the new connector you need to use [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.SQLServerBulkJdbcOptions](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/spark/SQLServerBulkJdbcOptions.scala) class to specify bulk copy options.